# Textbook advice

Tags: amateur-observing

I'm looking for resources/texts to learn more about stars and things. I stopped studying physics when I was 15, so I'm pretty uninformed. However, I do have a pretty good maths background (UG courses in Calculus, LA and Grad courses in Analysis, Probability Theory and Optimisation). I'd like a book that's rigorous but that doesn't rely on me knowing anything about physics. Possible?

Best,
S

Comment: What do you mean with _"stars and things"_? I'd start with some youtube videos on the topic, maybe then you can decide if you'd rather go into astronomy (astrophysics ) or even take a look at the very interesting philosophical part

Comment: This is in a related SE site, Space Exploration SE. you may find it a bit helpful, but it is related mostly to spaceflight and planetary exploration, rather than Astronomy. [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/12102). If it is possible, find a library or a used book store where you can hold and flip through several books on astronomy or space. This will give you a better sense of what you do or don't like in a book. Are you looking for math and equations, or more prose and explanations? Everyone is different.

Comment: You are on such a nice resource/text. I would suggest to try: 1) wikipedia 2) Astronomy SE.